# After casting a volatile variable in c, is the variable still volatile?

Tags: c, c99, volatile

Let's say that I have a static global variable a, that is cast to an int in a function call during init(). After init(), is *a* still volatile when used in the function my_function_2?

```
static volatile int a;

init(void)
{
  my_function_1((int)a);
}

my_function_2(void)
{
/* After init(), is a still volatile? */
}
```

Does *a* need to be re-qualified as volatile in my_function_2()? I'm using c99.

Comment: `a` will always be `volatile`, but when you do `casting` the compiler actually creates a temporary, which is not volatile of course.

Comment: " After init(), is `a` still volatile?" --> Yes, `a` is still `volatile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undefined behavior to refer to the value through a non-qualified type. If you "cast away" `volatile` you aren't allowed to access that memory location through a non-volatile qualified type.

C17 6.7.3/6:

> If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined

You can however still do a copy of it:

```
static volatile int a;
int b = a;      // ok, lvalue conversion, drops qualifiers during copy
*(int*)&a = ... // undefined behavior
```

Comment: Ok, if I still wanted a in my example to be volatile, could I re-qualify a as volatile in my_function_2()?

Comment: I don't think this answer addresses the question. `a` is not accessed through non-qualified type in question.

Comment: @LukesDiner, you would have to qualify it only, if you reference the original variable. In your example you pass by value, and the value itself is not affected.

Comment: @Devolus I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Does it matter if I pass a as value or not? My question is if I cast a to something other than volatile, can I re-qualify a in my_function_2() to avoid undefined behavior?

Comment: @LukesDiner What is "re-qualify"? If you copy a variable to another variable, the original remains unaffected. If you don't copy but attempt to modify it through a pointer, then it depends on how you attempt to do that.

Comment: @LukesDiner I somehow get the feeling that you think the result of `(int)a` that you pass to your function, might be linked to `a` in some way. That is not the case. The copy and the "real" `a` are different data objects and your cast does not affect `a` in any way.

Comment: It's a good feeling that this kind of u.b can be catched by enabling compiler warnings. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`  issues a `warning: initialization discards ‘volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]` or `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ discards ‘volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `a` will be volatile for it's entire lifetime. If you cast it to some different type and assign it to a new variable, then this new variable will not be `volatile` unless you specify it so.

`volatile` means that the compiler doesn't rely on a previously known value and should not apply appropriate optimizations, so if you cast that away and still reference it , than it is undefined behavior.

Here you don't need to declare b as volatile

```
volatile int a;

void func(int b)
{
     // This doesn't need to be volatile as it will never be changed from the outside, since it was passed by value.
     printf("%d\n", b);
}

init(void)
{
    // Access a and pass the value to func
    // This is fine, because volatile applies only to access of 'a'.
    func(a);
}
```

Another example:

```
void func(volatile int *p)
{
     // 'p' needs to be volatile as it will reference 'a' which is volatile
     printf("%d\n", *p);
}

init(void)
{
    func(&a);
}
```

Comment: *"... so if you cast that away, than it is undefined behavior."* This makes it sound as if code in question would be UB, which it's not.

Comment: I updated the phrase to make it more clearer.

Comment: @Devolus Thanks for your answer, but this still does not answer my question fully. Can I requalify a as volatile in my_function_2() to avoid undefined behavior?

Comment: I still think it is unclear: In order for UB to happen, object must be accessed thought non-volatile *pointer*. There is a step that requires taking address of object. It may to obvious to us, but may not be so for the asker.

Comment: The `volatile` attribute is required for access to the variable. I updated two examples.

Answer (score 1):

What volatile means is basically that it can be modified externally. This can never change. If you have declared a variable as volatile, then it is volatile.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what `(int)a` actually does.

Comment: @user694733 Yeah. Maybe I'll get back to it. Lundin already explained it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

A cast can only convert a value; it cannot affect an object (the memory of a variable). And values do not have qualifiers such as `volatile`.

When an object’s value is used in an expression, qualifiers are removed, per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called *lvalue conversion*. **If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the unqualified version of the type of the lvalue;…**

So, in `(int)a`, the `a` is converted from a `volatile int` lvalue to an `int` value **before the cast occurs**. The cast has no effect; it converts an `int` to an `int`. Also note that the value is cast—your title asks about “casting a volatile variable,” but it is impossible to cast a variable, because it is automatically converted to its value before the cast.

So the cast has no effect on `a`. The object `a` remains volatile. Its value is passed to `my_function_1` as a value without the `volatile` qualifier.